# Need to check multiple condition for Oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have a query below. i can check two conditions. If 'AAA' occurs it will show "AAA" with its id else it will show 'BBB'. I need to check more conditions like 
if 'AAA' occurs print "AAA" with its id
else 'BBB' occurs print "BBB" with its id
else 'ccc' occurs print "CCC" with its id
how to do this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT institution_id,

         CASE
              WHEN count(*) over(PARTITION BY institution_id) >=5 THEN 'AAA'
              WHEN count(*) over(PARTITION BY institution_id) >=5 THEN 'BBB'

         END AS status

FROM table
WHERE data LIKE '% AAA%'
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: Sample data and expected output will help here!!

Comment: Sample Data : Timeout, communication issue, system down, invalid response. If any of those error occurs 5 or ore times for the same id. Sample out output will be 'System down occurs for the id: 101' or 'Timeout occurs for the id:102'

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    INSTITUTION_COUNT
    AS
        (  SELECT INSTITUTION_ID, COUNT (*) AS INSTITUTION_COUNT
             FROM INSTITUTION
         GROUP BY INSTITUTION_ID)
SELECT E.INSTITUTION_ID          AS INSTITUTION_ID,
       DC.INSTITUTION_COUNT    AS INSTITUTION_COUNT,
       CASE
           WHEN DC.INSTITUTION_COUNT < 5 THEN 'Low'
           WHEN DC.INSTITUTION_COUNT >= 5 THEN 'High'
       END    AS STATUS
  FROM INSTITUTION E, INSTITUTION_COUNT DC
 WHERE E.INSTITUTION_ID = DC.INSTITUTION_ID;
```

Comment: I want to check some 4 to conditions, not 2 conditions. also this needs to be check whether the string occurs 5 times with same id. If yes then it need to display the string with id. i want to check this for 4 to 5 string occurrences.